# HOW TO Update URL (in address bar) with url shortener values from MYSQL column and shorten the URL (how to communicate with .htaccess/php/ajax/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, .htaccess, url

**What I have**: a link that looks like this: www.example.com/d/
<< the /d/ is actually a document.php file that I rewrote in .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^d/ documents.php [NC,L]
```

On this page, I will load  a random row from my MySQL database. It contains a unique key like this: 4d5GsV. I have around 1000 rows with different keys (column name UniqueKey). When I refresh it will show a different item (row).

**What I want:** I want the url to be like this: www.example.com/d/4d5GsV. I want the UniqueKey to be shown in the URL like that. If I refresh the page, it will show a new item and its UniqueKey value will be updated to the url in the address bar.

How can I do this? I've tried to fix this for hours but I can't seem to find any solution.

Thank you kindly in advance!

Comment: what specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Practically everything. I don't know how to get this working. I don't even know how to change the url in something like this: www.example.com/p?key=2fdfG5

Comment: can't answer *everything*.